# Why we get ORA-01003: no statement parsed error? What is meaning of it? In which scenario this error can be generated?

Tags: oracle

Why we get "ORA-01003: no statement parsed" error? What is the meaning of it? In which scenario this error can be generated? How to reproduce this error using sql developer?

Comment: Show your code please

Comment: Have you tried searching?

Comment: I am trying to reproduce this error using database only.I have not written any java code or SQL procedure.

Comment: In oracle document, they have not given any information.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ERRMG/ORA-00910.htm#ERRMG-GUID-D9EBDFFA-88C6-4185-BD2C-E1B959A97274

Answer (score 3):

> How to reproduce this error using sql developer?

Like this:

```
DECLARE
  NO_STATEMENT_PARSED EXCEPTION;
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT( NO_STATEMENT_PARSED, -1003 );
BEGIN
  RAISE NO_STATEMENT_PARSED;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why someone would ask such question.

Apart from obvious solution of MT0 you can also use this manual way:

```
DECLARE
    sqlStr VARCHAR2(1000);
    cur INTEGER;
    ret NUMBER;
BEGIN
    sqlStr := 'DELETE FROM emp WHERE 1 = 0';
    cur := DBMS_SQL.OPEN_CURSOR;
    --DBMS_SQL.PARSE(cur, sqlStr, DBMS_SQL.NATIVE); --> required
    ret := DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE(cur);       
    DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR(cur);

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( 'ret = ' || ret );

END;
```

You try to open a cursor without having any statement parsed before.